# Magento Cart Price Rule - Buy Any Combination of 5 SKU's, Get one Free! #FAIL

Tags: magento, conditional-statements, shopping-cart, magento-1.8

I've tried every combination of conditions and actions available but can't seem to crack this.  Should be simple.  Any help would be much appreciated.

I have 5 SKU's.  Lets call them A,B,C,D,E.  All of them are the same price (8.99). For every 5 you buy - you get one free.  This rule spans any combination of these SKU's.  Examples that should match:

- If 6 A's are in the cart, one is free (8.99 discount).
- If 2 A's, 2 B's and 2 C's are in the cart, one is free (8.99 discount).
- If 12 A's are in the cart, two are free (17.98 discount).
- If 6 C's, 6 D's and 6 E's are in the cart, three are free (26.97 discount).

Here's what I believe *should* accomplish this but doesn't even come close:

Conditions:
[image]

Actions:
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [magento.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extension did it for me:

http://blog.goods-pro.com/1733/magento-extension-buy-x-selection-of-products-get-another-y-selection-for-free/

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use event - observer approach for this, that will give you maximum flexibility.
You can build an observer that catches the add-to-cart event `sales_quote_add_item` and put your logic there.

Following code within your observer function will point you in the right direction:

// Added product:

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
$itemQty = $item->getQty();
$itemSku = $item->getSku();

// Change price of added product 
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newPrice);
```

// Get all products in cart:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    $itemSku = $item->getSku();
    $itemQty = $item->getQty();
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I'm using this extension (https://github.com/salgua/SalguaMagentoAddProduct) to add all the products to the cart via URL so not sure this will work.  I'm AFK for a few days but will try this out when I get a chance. Was hoping to use the rule system. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: This observer will also work when adding products to the cart via url. Your needs are too complex for price rules, but an observer would do the job.

Comment: Buy 5 get one free is too complex!?  I'd still prefer to use the rules if possible.  That's what it's built for.  What's the closest I can get using the rules system?